# Metadata review time?

Tags: ios, iphone, appstore-approval

So my app was accepted, but there was a problem with the website URL, I have fixed the issue, now I'm wondering the wait time for metadata? Is it the same as a regular review?

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns the policies and procedures of app distribution services, rather than programming. Please refer to: [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?‍](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165), [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?(https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem, and it took about a week after I responded.